# why my css code not working in my bootstrap file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my css code is not working with my html bootstrap when i am trying to put any changes in my css file it is not reflecting into browser butsome functions are working in my css files plz help

my html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contactCss.css">

<title>products</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container"/>
<div class="row"/>
<header>

<img src="image/Kayu-International-website-logo-final-transparent-300x100px.png" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4" alt="kayu">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="navigation" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-4" >
    <li  role="navigation" ><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li  role="navigation"><a href="products.html" role="navigation">products</a></li>
    <li  role="navigation"><a href="gallery.html" role="navigation">gallery</a></li>
    <li  role="navigation"><a href="distributors.html" role="navigation">distributors</a></li>
    <li  role="navigation"><a href="company.html" role="navigation">company</a></li>
    <li  role="navigation"><a href="#" role="navigation">special</a></li>
    <li  role="navigation"> <a href="contact.html" role="navigation">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>


<section class="s1">
    <div class="col-xx-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <address>
            <h3>KAYU International, Inc</h3>
            11117 SW Greenburg Rd.
            Tigard, OR 97223<br>
            U.S.A<br>
            Phone: (888) 558-5298<br>
            Local: (503) 557-7296<br>
            Fax: (503) 557-7262<br>
            Email: <a href="mailto:Wood@Kayu.com">Wood@Kayu.com</a><br>
            Hours: 7am-5pm, Monday-Friday<br>
        </address>
    </div>

<div class="col-xx-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <address>
            <h3>The KAYU Team</h3>
            Steve Wilson, President / CEO<br>
Mike Goodrich, Senior Vice President <a href="mailto:mike@kayu.com">mike@kayu.com</a><br> 
Robin Wilson, VP Product Development<br>
Gina Schaefer, Finance Manager <a href="mailto:gina@kayu.com">gina@kayu.com</a><br> 
Natalie Smith, Sales Manager <a href="mailto:natalie@kayu.com">natalie@kayu.com</a><br>
Debbie McPherson, Sales <a href="mailto:debbie@kayu.com">debbie@kayu.com</a><br>
Waldo Maya, Warehouse Manager<br>
Erick Huerta, Warehouse<br>
        </address>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xx-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <address>
            <h3>KAYU International, Indonesia & Malaysia</h3>
            Petrus Kuntjoro and Staff, Indonesia Agent and Chief Inspector.<br>
            Inspection and Logistics for KAYU.<br>
            <a href="mailto:wood@kayu.com">wood@kayu.com</a><br>
            Sudi Soh, Indonesia/Malaysia Agent and Logistics for KAYU.<br>
            <a href="mailto:wood@kayu.com">wood@kayu.com</a><br>
        </address>
        </div>
</section>
<section>
    <h3>Contact KAYU International using the form below or call today (888) 558-5298 for a local Distributor.</h3>

<form action="#" method="post" class="col-xx-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
<fieldset class="s2">
<div class="container"/>
<div class="row"/>
<label>Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required="required"><br>
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" required="required"><br>
        <label>Zip</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" required="required">
        <br><label>Products of Interest</label>
        <input type="text" name="poi" required="required">
        <br><textarea cols="20" rows="10">
            message:
        </textarea>
        <br><input type="submit" value="Send">  
</fieldset>
</form>
</section>



<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

my css code idont know what is happening but my code is not running thats all the details i can give to to you

```
    .s1{

    display: inline-block;

}
.s2{
            border:4px solid #ff0034;
            border-radius: 8px;
            display: block;
            align-items: center;


}
h3{
    color: #00FF00;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: what part of css is not working?  could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You have used bootstrap css and JS files from maxcdn server. So first download them if you want to modify css as it seems some css components are overlapping with bootstrap css.